# How to pass alias to my string in Cypress? cy.type(@alias) not working for me. I want to pass the text value I got in the previous text

Tags: javascript, cypress

This is my attempt to test

```
cy.get('.mat-tooltip-trigger.copy-link.ng-star-inserted').first().text().as('srt')

cy.get('input[formcontrolname="encoderAddress"]').type(this.srt)

cy.get('input[formcontrolname="encoderAddress"]').type(@srt)' - its not working too
```

Comment: I would solve this with cmd + c cmd + v, but the clipboard does not work in Cypress((

Answer (score 0):

An alias is a wrapper around the variable containing the text, you will need to unwrap it first.

```js
cy.get('.mat-tooltip-trigger.copy-link.ng-star-inserted').first().text().as('srt');

cy.get('@srt').then(srtText => {   // unwrapping happens here
  console.log(srtText)             // check that the text was captured
  cy.get('input[formcontrolname="encoderAddress"]').type(srtText);
})
```

But be warned, tooltip text will be hard to get hold of, as there's usually an animated hover effect before the tooltip appears. So the first line with `cy.get(...).first().text()` may not be capturing. Check in the console.