# Reusing variables later as integers/text later

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have tried getting cypress to save a text for later usage but I feel unable to reuse it as a variable

```
cy.get('.unrd').then(($span) => {
  const filteredunread = $span.text()
  cy.wrap(filteredunread).as('oldunreadmessage');
})
```

Codeblock to send a mail, wait and return to the inbox expecting an echo reply

```
cy.get('.unrd').then(($span) => {
  cy.get('@oldunreadmessage') //seen as object
  const newunread = $span.text()
  expect(newunread).to.eq(cy.get('@oldunreadmessage') +1)
})
```

This gives me errors such as:

```
expected '(27)' to equal '[object Object]1'
```

I have tried to use .as(). However I seem to be unable to properly resolve my old object as a text or integer constant.

Comment: See [How to pass alias to my string...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66432871/15239601)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part is fine, but because of the `cy.wrap` you need to use `should` or `then` on the `cy.get('@oldunreadmessage')`

```
cy.get('.unrd').then(($span) => {
    const newunread = $span.text();
    cy.get('@oldunreadmessage').should('have.text', newunread);
})
```

or

```
cy.get('.unrd').then(($span) => {
    const newunread = $span.text();
    cy.get('@oldunreadmessage').then((oldunread) => {
        expect(newunread)...
    }
})
```